# Cant find correct encoding when reading contents of HTTP response

Tags: .net, unicode, encoding, utf-8, webclient

I have this code that reads gzipped response from a url:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Proxy = new WebProxy() }) 
{
    webClient.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01");
    webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch");
    webClient.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6");

    webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie: ...");

    using (var responseStream = new GZipStream(webClient.OpenRead(url), CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            var textResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

but when I peek inside textResponse variable, it has characters like this `\u0411\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f`. 
What did I do wrong here? Constructing `StreamReader` without encoding parameter didn't help either.
The problem is - the server does **NOT** send back `Content-Type` response header, so I can't really tell what encoding the response have.

P.S. HttpWebRequest have the same problem

Comment: You're **assuming** the response is always gzip-compressed. You indicate that you will accept `gzip`, `deflate` or `sdch` encodings, but you're not checking the `Transfer-Encoding` response header to see how the response is actually encoded, if at all. You're also **assuming** the decompressed response is UTF-8 encoded. You're not checking the `Content-Type` response header to verify that. If the server is not sending `Content-Type` then it is broken. It **must** send `Content-Type` to indicate what it is sending, especially since you indicate you are willing to accept only two types of data.

Comment: `\u0411\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0440\u0443\u0441\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f` is the string `Белорусская`, is that what you are expecting to receive?  You did indicate that you are wiling to accept a response that uses the Russian language.

Comment: @RemyLebeau let me check for `Transfer-Encoding` header. and yes, I receive mostly Russian text

Comment: @RemyLebeau here are the headers - `Transfer-Encoding: chunked; Connection: close; Vary: Cookie; Pragma: no-cache; Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate; Content-Type: application/json; Server: nginx/1.0.10; Content-Encoding: gzip` (I omitted the Cookie header since its value is too long)

Comment: based on those headers, your code is correct, and your `textResponse` is clearly getting decoded into something readable. And there is a `Content-Type` header indicating JSON is being sent, but the `textResponse` content you showed is not valid JSON, unless you didn't show everything you are receiving. `\uXXXX` sequences are valid encoded characters inside of JSON data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I showed only part of it, the response is quite large to post it. it is indeed JSON, it's encoding that's messed up

Comment: in that case, the data you showed is perfectly valid data in JSON, it is just encoded, and I showed you what it looks like after decoding. Why do you think it is messed up? Have you read the [JSON spec](http://json.org) yet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122185/discussion-between-chester89-and-remy-lebeau).